CUDAError: Not enough memory for an RL environment using Gymnasium
from TTset_main import load_TTset

# File paths for training and validation data
filted_tset_path = "path.csv"
filted_vset_path = "path.csv"

# Load training and validation sets
TTset_training, TTset_vali, training_data_length = load_TTset(filted_tset_path, filted_vset_path)

# Extract frame tensors and labels from the training set
frame_tensors = []
labels = []

for inputs, targets in TTset_training:
    frame_tensors.append(inputs)
    labels.append(targets)

# Print dimensions of the frame tensors and labels
print("Inputs")
print("Dimension 1: ", len(frame_tensors)) #1927
print("Dimension 2: ", len(frame_tensors[0])) #1
print("Dimension 3: ", len(frame_tensors[0][0])) #3
print("Dimension 4: ", len(frame_tensors[0][0][0])) #60
print("Dimension 5: ", len(frame_tensors[0][0][0][0])) #230
print("Dimension 6: ", len(frame_tensors[0][0][0][0][0])) #230
print()
print("Training data length:", training_data_length)
print("Targets")
print("Dimension 1: ", len(labels)) #1927
print("Dimension 2: ", len(labels[0])) #1

import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium import spaces
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback
from tqdm import tqdm

# Custom gym environment for table tennis
class TableTennisEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, frame_tensors, labels, frame_size=(3, 60, 230, 230)):
        super(TableTennisEnv, self).__init__()
        self.frame_tensors = frame_tensors
        self.labels = labels
        self.current_step = 0
        self.current_substep = 0
        self.frame_size = frame_size

        self.n_actions = 20  # Number of unique actions
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(3, 60, 230, 230), dtype=np.float32)
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(self.n_actions)
        self.normalize_images = False

    def reset(self, seed=None):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.current_substep = 0
        return self.frame_tensors[self.current_step][self.current_substep], {}

    def step(self, action):
        reward = 1 if action == self.labels[self.current_step][self.current_substep] else -1
        self.current_substep += 1
        
        if self.current_substep >= len(self.frame_tensors[self.current_step]):
            self.current_substep = 0
            self.current_step += 1
        
        done = self.current_step >= len(self.frame_tensors)
        
        obs = self.frame_tensors[self.current_step][self.current_substep] if not done else np.zeros_like(self.frame_tensors[0][0])
        
        return obs, reward, done, {}

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        pass

# Reduce memory usage by processing in smaller batches
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: TableTennisEnv(frame_tensors, labels, frame_size=(3, 60, 230, 230))])

# Callback for progress bar during training
class ProgressBarCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, total_timesteps, verbose=0):
        super(ProgressBarCallback, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.total_timesteps = total_timesteps
        self.pbar = None

    def _on_training_start(self):
        self.pbar = tqdm(total=self.total_timesteps)

    def _on_step(self):
        self.pbar.update(self.model.n_steps)
        return True

    def _on_training_end(self):
        self.pbar.close()

# Set total timesteps for training
total_timesteps = 2048  # Adjust timesteps as needed

# Initialize PPO model with a smaller batch size
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, n_steps=64, tensorboard_log="./ppo_tt_tensorboard/")  # Reduce batch size
progress_bar_callback = ProgressBarCallback(total_timesteps=total_timesteps)

# Train the model
model.learn(total_timesteps=total_timesteps, callback=progress_bar_callback)

# Save the trained model
model.save("ppo_table_tennis")


I'm using the above code to train an RL model for classifying videos. The videos are input as tensors. The frame_tensors has dimensions 1927x1x3x60x230x230, and the labels has dimensions 1927x1. A single video is represented in 3x60x230x230 dimensions. I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/PJ/TTARnet_v2_to_lab_兆仁code/prototype.py", line 107, in <module>
    model.learn(total_timesteps=total_timesteps, callback=progress_bar_callback)
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py", line 315, in learn
    return super().learn(
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\on_policy_algorithm.py", line 313, in learn
    self.train()
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py", line 282, in train
    self.policy.optimizer.step()
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py", line 391, in wrapper
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py", line 76, in _use_grad
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py", line 168, in step
    adam(
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py", line 318, in adam
    func(params,
  File "C:\Users\User1\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py", line 581, in _multi_tensor_adam
    exp_avg_sq_sqrt = torch._foreach_sqrt(device_exp_avg_sqs)
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.27 GiB. GPU

Edit:
Solved the previous error. The new error is regarding GPU memory. I'm running this code on a 4070Ti, it has 12 gigs of memory but for some reason, the code is requiring more than that, about 2.27 GB more.
I decreased the batch size down to 4, and I cannot decrease the frame size anymore as I would lose a lot of information.
